# 19.10: How to bind FN+ESC shortcut to execute a script?

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys

Does anyone know how to bind <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> (or any other <kbd>Fn</kbd>+ combination) shortcut to execute a script in Ubuntu 19.10, using the default GNOME Desktop Environment?

The problem is that gnome-control-center does not recognize any shortcut combination involving the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key. I know how to get a keycode of <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> by xev command, but I do not know how to use it.

xev output:

```
KeyPress event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x6000001,
    root 0x16a, subw 0x0, time 4998279, (232,883), root:(352,997),
    state 0x0, keycode 37 (keysym 0xffe3, Control_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x6000001,
    root 0x16a, subw 0x0, time 4998284, (232,883), root:(352,997),
    state 0x4, keycode 133 (keysym 0xffeb, Super_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x6000001,
    root 0x16a, subw 0x0, time 4998287, (232,883), root:(352,997),
    state 0x44, keycode 93 (keysym 0x0, NoSymbol), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x6000001,
    root 0x16a, subw 0x0, time 4998292, (232,883), root:(352,997),
    state 0x44, keycode 93 (keysym 0x0, NoSymbol), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x6000001,
    root 0x16a, subw 0x0, time 4998299, (232,883), root:(352,997),
    state 0x44, keycode 133 (keysym 0xffeb, Super_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x6000001,
    root 0x16a, subw 0x0, time 4998305, (232,883), root:(352,997),
    state 0x4, keycode 37 (keysym 0xffe3, Control_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

Thanks very much for your advices.

Comment: Indeed, you can't. The Fn key on a laptop is a different beast and works on another level, not seen by the OS.